# ArgumentException: The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet<News>.Find' was of type 'string', which does not match the property type of int'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This error is thrown when I try to edit my post.

Here is my code:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    // issue 
    var news = await _context.News.FindAsync(id);
    if (news == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(news);
}
```

The debugger stops the code at

```cs
var news = await _context.News.FindAsync(id);
```

Code for my model is

```cs
public int id { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your name.")]
public string Author { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the title.")]
public string Title { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the issued date.")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a message.")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to change your method signature to this: `Edit(int? id)` You can also use `int` instead and skip the null check. Asp.net core will check that for you and return 404 if the `id` parameter is not suplied.

Comment: I changed my string to **Edit(int? id)**  and it returned a 404 with that being said i'm assuming the 'id' parameter is not supplied and how would one go about correcting this?

Comment: @masterofone are you really supplying the id? it should work; `site.com/controller/edit/1` where `1` is the id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> [FindAsync(Object[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.findasync?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-findasync-1(system-object()))
>
> Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with
> the given primary key values is being tracked by the context, then it
> is returned immediately without making a request to the database.
> Otherwise, a query is made to the database for an entity with the
> given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the
> context and returned. If no entity is found, then null is returned.

Therefore, if the primary key in your case has `int` type, than the `FindAsync()` parameter should be the same type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way would be

```
var _id=Convert.ToInt32(id);

  var news = await _context.News.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i=>i.id==_id);
```

but maybe it is better to change an action?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
```